# How to use ValueGeneratedOnUpdate() correctly?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I'm using **EF Core 2.1.0-preview1-final CF approach** with a **MS SQL Server 2014** and want to set on-update a time stamp in one column automatically. I already use `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` without any issues. When I insert a new record into my database the `InsertDateTimeUtc` column has the current UTC date and time value, the `UpdateDateTimeUtc` column has value `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000`, because it is a required column.

Here is my test model (entity class).

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime InsertDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDateTimeUtc { get; set; }


    public static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Person>();

        entity.Property(p => p.Name)
              .IsRequired();

        entity.Property(p => p.InsertDateTimeUtc)
              .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()")
              .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
              .IsRequired();

        entity.Property(p => p.UpdateDateTimeUtc)
              .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()")
              .ValueGeneratedOnUpdate()
              .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

As far as I tested `ValueGeneratedOnUpdate` does not work like I expected. If I update a record I would expect that the column `UpdateDateTimeUtc` will get the current UTC date and time value, but it does not change. The record (property `Name`) will be updated successfully - I set another value for property `Name` and could evaluate it.

I could found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581623/8330148) that contains following quote which seems to be from this [MS doc article - Generated Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties).

> This just lets EF know that values are generated for added or updated entities, it does not guarantee that EF will setup the actual mechanism to generate values.

But in mentioned MS doc article I could not find any information about the usage of `ValueGeneratedOnUpdate`. I already tried to use `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` - too without success.

Well, has somebody a hint how I could set a value for column `UpdateDateTimeUtc` in database automatically without any logic (like `person.UpdateDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;`) in code please? Or could provide somebody a link where I could read further information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Generated values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties) documentation topic (the link mentioned in the question) contains the following **Warning:**

> How the value is generated for added and updated entities will depend on the database provider being used. Database providers may automatically setup value generation for some property types, while others will require you to manually setup how the value is generated.
>
> For example, when using SQL Server, byte[] properties that are set as generated on add or update and marked as concurrency tokens, will be setup with the rowversion data type - so that values will be generated in the database. **However, if you specify that a DateTime property is generated on add or update, then you must setup a way for the values to be generated. One way to do this, is to configure a default value of GETDATE() (see Default Values) to generate values for new rows. You could then use a database trigger to generate values during updates (such as the following example trigger).**

followed by example trigger code.

So basically you are expected to create trigger for value generation on update. EF Core will just read back the value from the database after updating the record (similar to identity and calculated columns).

In your example, modify the generated migration `Up` method as follows:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Person",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        InsertDateTimeUtc = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()"),
        Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        UpdateDateTimeUtc = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()")
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Person", x => x.Id);
    });

// Add the following:   
migrationBuilder.Sql(
@"CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Person_UPDATE] ON [dbo].[Person]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) > 1) RETURN;

    DECLARE @Id INT

    SELECT @Id = INSERTED.Id
    FROM INSERTED

    UPDATE dbo.Person
    SET UpdateDateTimeUtc = GETUTCDATE()
    WHERE Id = @Id
END");
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe it was too late yesterday to find the information by my own in this article. I thought EF Core will do it by its own and creates a trigger (like you mentioned) or handles on-update behavior by itself internally.

Comment: Only for completeness for other users, the `Down` method must be extended by `DROP TRIGGER` logic as well! :)

Comment: @ChW True, but only if the trigger is not created in the same migration which creates the table. Otherwise, [dropping table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql) usually "*removes table and all data, indexes, triggers, constraints, and permission specifications for that table"* :)

Comment: Exactly, I already started to edit my comment to add this information, but I thought it seems to be clear and canceled editing. :D

Comment: @IvanStoev if `ValueGeneratedOnUpdate()` does not work without creating the trigger manually than what is the purpose of using this! Very confusing thing!

Comment: @IvanStoev Any explanation from you please?

Comment: @Tanvir Not sure what "explanation" do you want from me. I'm like you and any other EF Core user. I am *not* EF Core team member, hence cannot explain the reasons behind their design decisions, e.g. *why* is something done that way. My answer is based on the official documentation which I'm linking to. If you have complaints about functionality, the right place for that is their GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hey, I'm new to .Net. Isn't it breaking the migrations? I thought we were not supposed to touch the migration files because then we won't be able to change the state of database.

Comment: @honey_ramgarhia Normally we modify the model and auto-generate migration. But for some things like this which cannot be defined in the model (no attribute / fluent API), hence cannot be auto-generated, we can modify `Up` and `Down` methods accordingly, mainly inserting `Sql` method calls here and there. In this particular case we don't need to modify `Down` method because triggers are dropped along with the table. Basically `Down` method should revert everything that `Up` method is doing.

Comment: I think this is working as expected. When you create a record the column is initialized with GetDate(). When you update the record that column value is not updated BY DESIGN. Because it is set by the DB, not by the model object you are passing in.

Comment: Jason Taylor's [CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/439fcb0dc506ab45f38b5b7aca10c9a599348cd5/src/Infrastructure/Persistence/ApplicationDbContext.cs#L46) template has a better method for this scenario by overriding the `SaveChanges()` method and looking at the Entity state and manually setting the UpdatedAt field.

Comment: @KahanBhalani Hmm, you say "better"? What if the database is updated from code/direct SQL, or even another reverse engineered db context than the one having overridden `SaveChanges`? There is no better way for such things than letting the database do the job. Of course when it can. Same for default values, referential integrity (FK and unique constraints), cascade deletes etc.

Comment: "Better" would be for EF to be able to generate an UPDATE SQL statement like `UPDATE Table SET UpdateDateTimeUtc = GETUTCDATE() WHERE Id=xxx`. In this way, you truly have the UpdateDateTimeUtc updated with the right time. Any other approach is worse: using a trigger makes the performance much worse; setting DateTime.UtcNow in the code of SaveChanges() takes the time of the app server rather than the time of the DB server (i.e. what if the SQL statement takes 20 seconds to execute? You have an UpdateDateTimeUtc wrong!). Do you know if in the latest ver of EF Core there is anything like that?

Comment: Now, `GETUTCDATE` is a specific dialect of MS SQL Server, but in almost any other DBMS there is the equivalent function with the same result... And besides, in the worst case scenario EF could expose something from the PropertyBuilder that allow the user to inject specific SQL code for this function...

Comment: @CristianoGhersi I don't know how to say it better. EF Core is just one of the many ways you can modify the database. The database is the actual shared repository between potentially many different clients. Thus the database is the best place for such behaviors. What could EF6, EF Core, NHibernate or whatever external data access library absolutely does not matter.

Answer (score -1):

I've the same issue but when i remove IsRowCreated(); from the context it works .

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34601468)