# Code First EF Concurrency Token with Guid

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use a GUID as the concurrency token but every time I try to insert a record there is an exception about null value not being able to be added.

Generated SQL and Exception Message:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Guid), @p1='?' (Size = 10) (DbType = AnsiString), @p2='?' (Size = 150) (DbType = AnsiString)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Application] ([Id], [Code], [Name])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
SELECT [Version]
FROM [Application]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = @p0; System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Version', table 'MyCompany.dbo.Application'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

```
public class Application
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        // A concurrency token for use with the optimistic concurrency checking
        public Guid Version { get; set; }
    }
```

With the model Builder:

```
builder.Property(c => c.Version)
                .IsConcurrencyToken()
                .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

Basically, I need advice about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The linked question is relating to DateTime as the concurrency token. From Microsoft Reference: For example, when using SQL Server, values will be automatically generated for GUID properties (using the SQL Server sequential GUID algorithm). However, if you specify that a DateTime property is generated on add, then you must setup a way for the values to be generated.

Comment: Yes you are right, i removed the close vote. (for reference purpose, this was the linked article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634598/how-to-use-valuegeneratedonupdate-correctly)

Comment: @nilsK could you please put yours as the anwser. I haven't found another solution that works, so I would like to award the points to you.

Comment: If you found a solution in that other post, spend your points there. Glad you found a fix.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things I see that need correction.

The `modelbuilder` statement should be modified as below

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Application>().Property(app => app.Version).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate().IsConcurrencyToken();
```

Bear in mind that there is no value generation strategy that is specified on Version property. When we generate a migration with this state, the generated Migration.cs file assigns a defaultValue `new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));` inside of the   `Up()` method. Below is an example

[image: Contact Entity]

[image: Migration without Required attribute and without any value generation strategy]

On the other hand, if you want a new Guid to be added each time you insert a new row into the table, you should use a computed field. Below two images show the structure of the Version property decorated with attributes and the generated Migration. Also, below line code needs to be added to mark the computation.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().Property(t => t.Version).HasComputedColumnSql("NEWID()");
```

[image: Migration with Computed Field]

[image: Updated Entity With Computed Field]

With the changes mentioned, you'll have a new `Guid` successfully generated for every row inserted.

Comment: You made a lot of effort with your answer, but please do not post code in images. Use the code formatting feature while editing your answers/questions. Text in images can neither be searched (i.e. SO search or google search) nor copy&pasted. The [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) may be worth a read.